# Making MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, backend

I'm currently working on a project, the admin of the application must be able to add/edit these information.

```
Class(className)  
Teacher(teacherName,teacherInfo,teacherPicture,teacherEmail)  
Practice(practiceName,practiceDate,practiceDescription,practiceDocs)
```

I tried making 3 tables of which the class would be the relational table containing the keys of teacher and practice, but that way I can't add only the subject without teachers and practices or add a Teacher and then afterwards assign him a class, or remove him from a class. So my question is how would I go about doing this or if you could point me to some good read for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you have a *practices* table, a *teachers* table and a *classes* table, with relation fields put directly on those tables.

For you to be able to create teachers, classes and practices individually, you must take that relationship fields out and put the relations into separate tables.

So, instead of having, for example, a *classes* table with a teacher field, have a *classes* table without any field related to the teacher and another separate table *classes_teachers* where you'd have a unique identifier for the association, the id of the teacher and the id of the class.

The type of relationship your current schema provides is called a **1 by n** relationship.

The kind of relationship you need is a **n by n** relationship.